# How to find Elixir files in OSX?

Tags: macos

I'm playing with the Elixir language but I'm stuck with this simple question. I'm looking at [this page](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html#running-scripts). In order to run a script I need to save the text file. But where do I save it? I could not find the Elixir directory. If I save ıt to desktop, for instance, it cannot find it. Thanks

I'm using OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are stored in the `bin` directory.

You can find the bin folder in your OsX in the [following way](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2288439?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: Thanks. I can now find the `bin` folder and Elixir is there but now I have another question: How do I save the text file to  `/usr/local/bin`? That path is not visible when I try to move the file to there. Thanks.

Comment: http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#setting-path-environment-variable

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the content of that link. Instead I used the information on [this page](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/) to create a `.bash_profile` page and added `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/elixir/bin"` to that page. But this changed nothing. I still don't know how to save the file so that I can run it as a script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the elixir code files inside bin folder to run. If you added elixir to your path `elixir` command should be available on your terminal. Save your elixir code file anywhere you want and run the script from terminal with `elixir sample.ex` assuming your file name is sample.ex.